# How to use timestamp to get recent files in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a folder filled with logs of files. Logs are generated weekly.
For example.

> /path/week20a.log 
>   /path/week20b.log 
>   /path/week29d.log 
>   /path/week30c.log 
>   /path/week31a.log 
>   /path/week32a.log

I want to get the most recent log for the last week (last week meaning the latest of the last week's log file before this weeks) and the week before it. 
In this case,

> /path/week21d.log 
>   /path/week20c.log

I have two subroutine functions for this that look like:

```
sub getweek {
$week = ???; #where week should return one of the 'week***' listed above
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name('*$week.log')
                            ->in(mydir);

my @files_with_mtimes = map +{ name => $_, mtime => (stat $_)[9] }, @files;
our @sorted_files = reverse sort { $a->{mtime} <=> $b->{mtime} } @files_with_mtimes;

return $sorted_files[0]{name};
}
```

The problem is I'm getting current week using `Time::Piece->new->strftime("%V")` and then I am doing that `-2` to get the week before last. I'm hardcoding in the assumption that the most recent log from 2 weeks ago will always be there and will be the one before last. What if there is no run last week? In which case, last log will be the week before that and the one before that will be the one before that week.

How can I have two subroutines, where one gets last week's log, `Time::Piece->new->strftime("%V")-1` IF IT EXISTS AND IF NOT, DECREMENTS TO FIND THE WEEK BEFORE THAT and then based of that does something similar to find the last log before that one.

Comment: So on week 41 you'd want week40d.log and week21d.log?

Comment: @Schwern That's right. Let's use week 41 as an example. If by the time I run the script, there is already a log for week 41, I don't want to use that until week 42. I would still want it to grab 40d and 21d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use File::Basename qw( basename );

my @qfns = ...;
my $target_week = ...;

my %qfns_by_week;
for my $qfn (@qfns) {
   my $fn = basename($qfn);
   my ($week) = $fn =~ /(\d+)/
      or warn("Skipping $qfn: Unrecognized format\n"), next;

   next if $week > $target_week;

   push @{ $qfns_by_week{$week} }, $qfn;
}

my ($week2, $week1) = sort { $b <=> $a } keys(%qfns_by_week);

my @latest_qfns;
push @latest_qfns, ( reverse sort @{ $qfns_by_week{$week1} } )[0] if defined($week1);
push @latest_qfns, ( reverse sort @{ $qfns_by_week{$week2} } )[0] if defined($week2);
```

Note that the final two lines assume that the path and the leading part of the file name are the same for all logs of the same week.

Comment: I finally figured out the problem. I tried running on my local disk and it runs fine. Apparently on the central disk containing the whole teams files, they had changed the file names to a format that looks like "slom-sc3-master-19ww***". So when I run the script there, it causes these issues. I had to mv the directory with new names to my local one.  I tried modifying to "/(.*\d.*\d+.*\d+)/" but it says the Argument "slom-sc3-master-19ww**" isn't numeric in sort at.....

Comment: `/^\D+\d+\D+\d+\D+(\d+)/`

Comment: It's finally working. Thank you so much! I do have a question though to make this code "safe" for every situation. The script is taking a look at weeks and returning the last log and the most previous one before that. Some weeks, there are multiple models of each log. Like 30a, 30b, etc. How can I ensure that it only returns the latter? The script will be set to do autoruns, so I wouldn't want to go in manually to ensure that there are only two paths each time. I just added in a test log called "30a" to check and it returned 31a, 30c, 30a since both fall under week 30.....

Comment: Would I just do an if statement to check if there is more than one file in the array and than compare the letters and take the "greater" one.

Comment: I missed that you only wanted the latest one of each week. A made a simple change that assumes the `/path/slom-sc3-master-` part is the same for all logs of a week.

Comment: That works perfectly!!! The only thing to note for other viewers is that the match will still have to be "/^\D+\d+\D+\d+\D+(\d+)/" and not just "/(\d+)/". When that part isn't updated too it just returns week32a.

Comment: The answer is correct for the question, and `/^\D+\d+\D+\d+\D+(\d+)/` would not answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

My take on the problem: Find latest weekly files for the last two weeks for which there are files.

One way: Sort all files by timestamps, group into weeks and take latest from each, for the last two.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say', 'state';
use List::MoreUtils qw(part);
use Time::Piece;

my $dir = shift;
die "Usage: $0 directory\n" if not $dir or not -d $dir;

my @files =                       # arrayrefs: name, secs since epoch    
    sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
    map { [$_, (stat $_)[9]] } 
    grep { -f } 
        glob "\Q$dir\E/*.log";

my $dt = Time::Piece->localtime;
my $curr_week = $dt->week;
my $curr_yr   = $dt->year;

my @parts = part {
    state $this_week = $curr_week;
    my $t = $dt->strptime($_->[1], "%s");
    if ($t->year != $curr_yr) {
        $this_week += 51 ;
        $curr_yr = $t->year;
    }
    $this_week - $t->week;  # partition index: week offset
} @files;

# Remove the first element if it is for the current week
shift @parts  if $parts[0] and 
    Time::Piece->strptime($parts[0]->[0][1], "%s")->week == $curr_week;

my @last_in_weeks = map { $_->[0] // () } grep { defined } @parts;    
say $_->[0] for @last_in_weeks[0,1];
```

This can be optimized, in the first place by cutting off week-based partitioning of all files as soon as we have the needed number of weeks (two in this case).<sup>†</sup>

Comments

- Filelist is built assuming that all files are directly in the given directory. The [`\Q...\E`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) in `glob` is there to deny a (rare but possible) injection bug. Since it also quotes possible spaces in directory names we don't need to double quote the glob
- Files are sorted in reverse by modification time and since we'll need timestamps later they are kept, so `@files` carries two-element arrayrefs. A more convenient and less efficient option is to pack name and timestamp in a hash
- [List::MoreUtils::`part`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#part-BLOCK-LIST) assigns elements into groups, which are arrayrefs in the returned list. They are *indexed by* what the block returns; so files in the week with offset 2 (returned from the block) go into the arrayref which is the third element of the returned list. Thus there are `undef` elements when there are no files for some weeks
- For partitioning, the week of each file is subtracted from the `$curr_week` so that the partition index starts at the most recent week. (Then the first element of `@parts` is removed if it has files from the current week, since the current week's logs are not wanted.)  However, ...
- ... `Time::Piece::week` returns the week number *in this year*. So at end of January `$t->week` may be 3, nicely subtracted from `$this_week` (32 at time of this writing) for index 29, but as we keep processing the next file, from end of December, is week 51! A negative offset is a no-go for `part`. So `$this_week` need be `+= 51` every time year changes

This code, and the version below, **uses timestamps to find out the week**.  If the week should be pulled from the filename instead, then replace `$dt->week` with a simple regex prying the week number out of a filename, and take the first file for that week (if sorted in reverse). Also drop the `$dt` altogether and year-based considerations aren't needed either; it's much simpler that way.

---

<sup>†</sup> Best done manually, since `part` can be cleanly interrupted only by throwing an exception (then `eval`-ed) and exceptions in general shouldn't be used for flow control.

```
my $dt = Time::Piece->localtime;

my ($week, $prev_week) = ($dt->week) x 2;
my $prev_year = $dt->year;
my @latest_weekly;

foreach my $rf (@files) {
    $dt = $dt->strptime($rf->[1], "%s");

    if ($dt->year != $prev_year) {
        $prev_week += 51;
        $prev_year = $dt->year;
    }

    # New week? This first file in the new week is the latest one
    if ($dt->week < $prev_week) {   
        push @latest_weekly, $rf; 
        last if @latest_weekly >= 2;  # really take only two
        #$prev_week = $dt->week;      # if we are to continue
    }
}

say $_->[0] for @latest_weekly;
```

This is no harder and is far more efficient (it's more efficient without cutting it off at the second week, as well). However, the code using `part` I think is more general and maintainable -- more easily changed to meet other ends.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! I have two questions here. How can I specify to only search for ".log" files? The directory contains other types of files as well that I don't want. Also, like you mentioned in your post about the indexing, it's a problem when I run the code. Because I am in week 32, I want to return week 31 and week 30 but it is returning week 29 and 28 instead. I want it to go back to last week's log and the one before that. If I am in week 32, and week 32 logs are generated, I want 31. If I'm in week 32 and 32 logs aren't generated yet, I still want 31.

Comment: @sfr  (1) Use `glob "$dir/*.log";` -- it's much like shell's glob-ing (and then for safety really `glob "\Q$dir\E/*.log";`)  (2) It should give weeks 31 and 30, by all means -- if there are files during those weeks. (Note that the code decides the week by the timestamp, not by a label in filename.)   I'll check, perhaps there's a bug of sorts so that it skips over the past week or a few (i did test, but...)

Comment: Oh ok. I would appreciate that because it keeps going back to older weeks and skipping over the more recent ones.

Comment: i tried to specify the .log in glob, and now it is just returning the very first .log file that was ever made from like week 7.

Comment: Why is `stat` being used? You should be using the week num in the file name, not the file modification time.

Comment: @sfr  I tested again, on directories with multiple files from this week, and from last week, and from the week before last (and older) -- both programs print the last file from the previous week and the last file from the week before that.  (the second code snippet needs the beginning part of the first one copied). For directories with not so recent files the program print latest files from the last two available weeks, excluding the current week.

Comment: @sfr  i use `glob "\Q$dir\E/*.log";` and I do get all files -- but only one, _the latest from that week_ (as required?), is printed.

Comment: I was using stat initially but I got rid of it afterwards.

Comment: @ikegami  "_Why is `stat` being used_"  -- on purpose, since OP used it and it is a one reliable measure of when a log was produced.  Above all I wasn't sure what was wanted and chose timestamp

Comment: Quite the contrary, `stat` is not the most reliable. If a log file name says it's for week 31, and `stat` says the mtime is for week 32, the log is for week 31. (This is even an entirely likely situation here. The OP has since mentioned the logs are copied from one machine to another, and this could affect the mtime.)